# OpenID reauthentication for signing off work in the application

Tags: openid, access-token, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I have a SPA application with some WebAPI methods that are protected with OpenID authentication. A user first signs into the SPA application, then carries out some work in the application and is then required to sign off on this work by reauthenticating with the identity provider.

The SPA application uses oidc-client-js. To force reauthentication we pass in the prompt parameter with value 'login'. The user then receives a new access token that can be used to call the WebAPI method to sign off on the work.

The signoff WebAPI method must ensure that the work is signed off with the same identity that logged into the application in the first place. When the application was still using WsFed with session cookies (we are now changing it to OpenID), the WebAPI was able to assert the incoming identity is the same as the current user identity. But, since with OpenID we do not want to use session cookies, perhaps the WebAPI could ask for both the login access token and the signoff access token to assert both are for the same identity. That does not even seem to make sense. Can it even be done? Perhaps the signoff WebAPI only need to assert that the signoff identity has permission to sign off on the work, irrespective of the identity of the user who logged into the application in the first place.

Second, the user must sign off separately for separate bits of work. So, when a user carries out work on resource A, signs off on the work on resource A by reauthenticating with the identity provider, and subsequently carries out work on resource B, the WebAPI needs to ensure that the work on resource B is signed off with an access token obtained for resource B, and not with the access token obtained earlier for resource A.

When reauthenticating for signing off on work, we specify the resource Guid in the redirect uri (this might require specifying a wildcard in the reply url in ADFS? It does not appear to require special configuration in IdentityServer3). When we were using WsFed the signoff WebAPI method could assert the current request url is the same as the redirect uri contained in the incoming authentication ticket. When using OpenId, I don't think the access token contains the redirect uri for which it was issued, right? So how can the signoff WebAPI assert the access token was issued for the current resource being signed off?

Below is some code based on how we did things with WsFed, but I'm not sure this is going to work with OpenID.

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
    new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        TokenProvider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = context =>
            {
                var incomingIdentity = context.Ticket.Identity;

                // is the redirect uri even in the authentication ticket?
                incomingIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(Business.ClaimTypes.RedirectUri,
                    context.Ticket.Properties.RedirectUri));

                // without session cookies, do we even have a current user at this stage?
                var user = context.OwinContext.Authentication.User;
                if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    incomingIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(Business.ClaimTypes.RequestedBy,
                        user.Identity.Name));
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

    });
```

and

```
public class SignoffAuthorizedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var claimsPrincipal = (ClaimsPrincipal)filterContext.HttpContext.User;

        var redirectUriClaim = 
            claimsPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == Business.ClaimTypes.RedirectUri);
        if (redirectUriClaim == null || filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != 
            new Uri(redirectUriClaim.Value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }

        var requestedByClaim = 
            claimsPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == Business.ClaimTypes.RequestedBy);
        if (requestedByClaim == null || claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name != 
            requestedByClaim .Value)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);                
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Did you solve the problem eventually?